# creating extension and trying to change webpage background colour but failing on permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm trying to change the background colour for the active tab's web page using the following code:

code from popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
```

code for manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>"]
```

The extension error log reports this as the problem:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html".
Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

For the above error i had google.co.uk in my active tab and i've also tried other web pages to confirm the problem isn't specific to a particular web page.

Why do my permissions not cover this?

Comment: The error message says you can't modify the contents of the default new tab page. It means you've clicked the icon when the new tab page was active. You can suppress the error by checking lastError like chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"}, ()=>chrome.runtime.lastError)

Comment: I'm trying to change the background colour, so suppressing the error doesn't solve this. I have been following this youtube example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEEFrnBhY4I&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlWil-vQ-y7NR902ovyq1Xi&index=34

Comment: Note: I'm not using the browserAction api in my code like in the youtube video. My code in the popup.js page is this document.getElementById('someElementID').addEventListener('click', function(){chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});})

Comment: My understanding is the activeTab permission should allow this code to change the background colour for the active tab.

Comment: Like I said the problem occurred only when you clicked the extension icon while the default new empty tab page was active. Not sure how I can rephrase my comment...